# Python black formatter for vscode not formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-black

I'm trying to use [black as a formatter](https://pypi.org/project/black/) for Python on VS Code on Ubuntu 20.04 but it's not working on auto save.

I've selected `black` in `Python>Formatting:Provider`. I'm using prettier as my default formatter for which I added a .prettierignore, disabled, and uninstalled to make sure it wasn't interfering with black. I also added a custom path to `./local/bin/black`. It works though when I run it through the terminal. How do I make it work?

```
{
  editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
    "-l 120"
  ],
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "python.formatting.blackPath": "./local/bin/black"
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have on your settings.json for `python.formatting.*`. Also, `./local/bin/black` could be the wrong directory (could be the directory for the current workspace). Is there really a `.` at the start?

Comment: @GinoMempin I edited the question. Before I change the path the default was `path` which is working. But this shouldn't be the problem here. `./local/bin/black` still executes black.

Comment: On VS Code, open the Output tab (normally on the bottom panel) and select Python from the dropdown. Do you see any messages about black?

Comment: Only outputs from pylint.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are only a few settings you need to [setup `black` as a formatter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting) on VS Code. It seems you got most of it right, but I am doubtful about using relative paths for `blackPath` (VS Code should have shown an error if the path is indeed incorrect).

**I suggest switching to absolute paths.**

Here are my settings:

```json
// User Settings

"editor.defaultFormatter": null,
"editor.formatOnSave": false,  // enable per language
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/local/bin/black"

// Workspace Settings

"python.formatting.blackPath": "/absolute/path/to/venv/with/black",
"python.formatting.blackArgs": [
    "-l 120"
],
```

First of all, I suggest getting rid of the `editor.defaultFormatter` setting (or just set it back to the default `null`). Instead of setting a default for everything, configure your formatter for *each* language and for *each* extension. Here, it's `null` and then I configure `python`-specific settings then I have separate ones for other languages (ex. JS and C++). You mentioned something about Prettier, and that could be interfering with VS Code using black.

Second, make sure you are modifying the correct settings. VS Code has [3 sets of settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings): **User**, **Workspace**, and **Folder**. I normally have the `formatOnSave` enabled for Python on the **User** settings, and `provider` set to `black` (using system-wide installed `black`). On a specific workspace, I have a virtual environment and I override the `blackPath` to the `black` specifically installed on that virtual environment. You can also just put all the settings in the **User** settings or use the same system-wide-installed `black`. But the main point here is to use absolute paths for both (basically copying the output of `which black` from the console).

Note that, if you specified `blackPath` to point to a particular virtual environment, make sure to [select that same virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) on your workspace.

Lastly, you can check for any issues from the Output tab > Python:

[image: VS Code screenshot of Output]

Comment: Thanks. `home/<usr_name>/.local/bin/black` worked. I will take your advice about the default formater.

Comment: I can not get the line length to work. I put for example 500 but it still does it at the default length (80, 90 or whatever it is). In the terminal (output tab) I get ```~\Desktop\fastapi_training\myenv\Scripts\black --line-length 500 --diff --quiet ~\Desktop\fastapi_training\postgre_sql_app\crud.py
cwd: ~\Desktop\fastapi_training```

Comment: @elano7 It might be dependent on the line being formatted, since the [black code style mentions](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#line-length) that "*Black will try to respect that. However, sometimes it won’t be able to without breaking other rules.*" I recommend to try it outside of VS Code (ex. do `black -l 500 file.py`) to see if it's a black or VS Code issue, then post a _separate_ question for that _specific_ issue.

Comment: @GinoMempin  thanks, you were right. It respects my rule on method chaining or long strings, but on a tuple it has its own rules.

Answer (score 2):

I was also having the issue. What solved the issue for me was after downloading the Black formatter extension and once the document was open I did a right-click with the mouse and then press "format document". Choose black. I was good to go and had no more issues after that.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "editor.defaultFormatter" inside python if you already set default formatter as black but it still doesn't work. This line also is created if you right click => Format Document => Select default Formatter.

```
{
    "black-formatter.importStrategy": "fromEnvironment",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter", #1 try adding this
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter" #2 this did nothing on Save
}
```

p/s: I'm using VSCode Windows version 1.84.0

Comment: the "ms-python.black-formatter" got it working for me! thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I had one invalid argument in black arguments.

Answer (score 0):

My VSCode version is Version: `1.72.2`. I installed python `3.10` using Anaconda and the black version installed by conda is `19.10b0`.

I have configured `"python.formatting.provider": "black"` in VSCode `settings.json` and black doesn't format.

Once I manully update black to `22.10.0`, the format works properly.

Answer (score 0):

For the people that got to this point and still haven't found an answer to this and tried multiple solutions, including installing the microsoft black formatter extension:

- disable it
- add the following to your user settings and workspace settings:

```json
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": null,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
```

Comment: I got hits far, but your solution still didn't worked for me